# How to import a page within a page in Ionic 3

Tags: html, typescript, ionic3

[This is the app component. It gives an error that it can't find module pages/question/pages/question1/question1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2CCK.png)
[This is the app module where I declared the question1. still the same error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G5Bf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your import path is wrong, it should be as,

```
import {question1} from './pages/questions/pages/question1'
```

Comment: thank you for the correction. Now it has an error with the imported name. It says that it has no exported member.